# Делаю поиск по тегам, но статьи с выставленными тегами не появляются

Tags: html, python, django

Делаю, чтобы по выбору тегов, доупустим тег `python`, и должны появиться все статьи с тегом `python`, но по нажатию на тег статьи не отображаютcя в шаблоне `list.html`

p.s.: если хотите обьединить с прошлым моим вопрос, то они разные: этот про то, как выводить статьи, а тот был про ошибку - не мог migrate'нуть taggit

views.py

```
def post_list(request, tag_slug=None):
    object_list = Articles.objects.all()
    tag = None

    if tag_slug:
        tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
        object_list = object_list.filter(tags__in=[tag])

    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3) # 3 posts in each page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer deliver the first page
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'news/list.html', {'page': page,
                                                   'posts': posts,
                                                   'tag': tag})
```

models.py

```
class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default="default_value")
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

шаблон с тегом, на который нужно нажать

```
{% extends "ShapeHtml/wrapper.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {% for article in object_list  %}

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
          <p><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ article.img.url }}"/></p>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
          <a href="{% url 'article_detail' article.pk %}"> <h1> {{article.title}} </h1> </a>
          <h3 align="right">{{article.date|date:"d-m-Y"}}</h3>



        {% for tag in article.tags.all %}
            {{ tag }}
        {% endfor %}

      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

list.html шаблон с листом статей, в которых есть этот тег

```
{% include "news/posts.html" with page=posts %}

<p class="tags">
    Tags:
    {% for tag in article.tags.all %}
        <a href="{% url "news:post_list_by_tag" tag.slug %}">
            {{ tag.name }}
        </a>
        {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</p>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('', ArticlesList.as_view(), name='articles_list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', ArticleDetail.as_view(), name='article_detail'),
    path('aboutUs', views.aboutUs, name='aboutUs'),
    path('tag/<tag_slug>.+/', views.post_list, name='post_list_by_tag'),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: из вашего кода следует, что вы пытаетесь вывести `post`, где его нет, а есть только `posts`, который вообще итерируемый объект (вроде QuerySet). Будьте внимательнее, и прошу читать, как пишите вопросы. как то надоело править за вами сообщения, а читать с ошибками вообще нет желания

Comment: извини я постараюся завтра нормально задать ок ?

Comment: хорошо. давай по теме. выведи список статей, а не 1 статью

Comment: Все я добавил все что сделал в код что теперь ? исправил пару недочетов

Comment: Пройдите туториал. Если вы будете и дальше задавать вопросы не изучая основ, сообщество перестанет реагировать на ваши вопросы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{# Код автора #}
{% include "news/posts.html" with page=posts %}

<p class="tags">
    Tags:
    {% for tag in article.tags.all %}
        <a href="{% url "news:post_list_by_tag" tag.slug %}">
            {{ tag.name }}
        </a>
        {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</p>
```

Так как это шаблон `'news/list.html'`, который вы пытаетесь отрендерить во вьюхе, то в контексте, исходя из `return render(request, 'news/list.html', {'page': page, 'posts': posts, 'tag': tag})`, контест будет содержать `page`, `posts` и `tag`. 
Далее по коду в шаблоне вы пытаетесь вставить `news/posts.html`. Если он имеется в вашем вопросе - обозначьте его, а пока вы непонятно что выводите.

Что касается вывода, как я говорил в *комментариях* - вам нужно выводить статьи из posts (который язвляется `QuerySet` от `Articles`). А теги выводит тогда, когда работаете с одиночной статьей `Articles`

```
{% for article in posts %}
  {{ article.title }}

  <div class='tags'>
    {% for tag in article.tags.all %}
      {{ tag }}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Если вас устраивает как выводится ваш шаблон списка постов - то используйте его

```
{% include '<шаблон с тегом, на который нужно нажать>' with object_list=posts %}
```

И пройдите уже туториал, хоть для Django 1.9-1.11 на русском на [djbook.ru](https://djbook.ru) ибо, как я говорил в прошлых ваших вопросах, это основы.